# Arduino Bootloader for ATmega168PA

Tags: arduino, atmega, bootloader

I have burned an **arduino bootloader** to an **ATmega168PA**. I want to use the **internal 8MHz oscillator** for the ATmega, and I used an **arduino Uno** as an **ISP**. For that, I did the following:

- Created the directory at Documents/Arduino/hardware/breadboard/avr. In there I placed a **boards.txt** file, and a bootloaders folder, which contained the **.hex file**. Both files can be found at the end.
- I found the hex file I used in this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sleemanj/optiboot/master/dists/diy_atmega8_series_ARDUINO_1_0_x.zip). From it, I used the **optiboot_atmega168pa_8000000L_57600.hex**

The burning of the bootloader completed **successfully**. Also I **successfully uploaded** a blink example to my ATmega168PA via the arduino ISP and the Arduino IDE.

**The problem** is that when I try to upload something **a second time**, I get this error:

[image].

If I reburn the bootloader, I can again successfully upload a sketch. But once more, I cannot upload a second time.

*optiboot_atmega168pa_8000000L_57600.hex file:*

```
 :103E00001F92CDB7DEB7112484B714BE982F9D70D2
:103E100009F0C4D082E08093C00088E18093C100A3
:103E200086E08093C20080E18093C4008EE0A1D040
:103E3000812C912C93E0F92EEE24E39425E0D22EF0
:103E400031E1C32E8AD0813479F487D0898397D029
:103E50008981823811F482E005C0813811F486E04E
:103E600001C083E073D06FC0823411F484E103C0D9
:103E7000853419F485E08BD066C0853541F46DD06A
:103E8000882E6BD0912C982A880C991C5BC08635A3
:103E900021F484E07CD080E0E5CF843609F036C0A0
:103EA0005CD05BD0B82E59D0A82E00E011E055D0E0
:103EB000F80181938F01BE12FACF61D0F5E4AF1201
:103EC00001C0FFCFF401F7BEE89507B600FCFDCFB7
:103ED000B401A0E0B1E02C911296AD01415051091E
:103EE000FA01808130E0382BFB010901E7BEE8953B
:103EF00011246E5F7F4FBA12EECFF401D7BEE89562
:103F000007B600FCFDCFC7BEE8951DC0843769F435
:103F100024D023D0B82E21D032D08401F80185914D
:103F20008F0114D0BA94D1F70EC0853739F427D059
:103F30008EE10CD084E90AD08BE094CF813511F466
:103F400088E017D01CD080E101D07CCF9091C000D8
:103F500095FFFCCF8093C60008958091C00087FF35
:103F6000FCCF8091C00084FD01C0A8958091C6005F
:103F70000895E0E6F0E098E1908380830895EDDF16
:103F8000803219F088E0F5DFFFCF84E1DFCFCF93F7
:103F9000C82FE3DFC150E9F7CF91F1CF282E80E0A1
:083FA000E8DFE0E0FF270994CF
:023FFE000206B9
:0400000300003E00BB
:00000001FF
```

*Boards.txt file:*

```
atmega168pabb.name=ATmega168PA on a breadboard (8 MHz internal clock)

atmega168pabb.upload.protocol=arduino
atmega168pabb.upload.maximum_size=14336
atmega168pabb.upload.maximum_data_size=1024

atmega168pabb.upload.speed=19200
#atmega168pabb.upload.speed=115200
atmega168pabb.upload.tool=arduino:avrdude

atmega168pabb.bootloader.tool=arduino:avrdude
atmega168pabb.bootloader.low_fuses=0x62
atmega168pabb.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDF
atmega168pabb.bootloader.extended_fuses=0xF8
atmega168pabb.bootloader.file=optiboot_atmega168pa_8000000L_57600.hex
atmega168pabb.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
atmega168pabb.bootloader.lock_bits=0x3F

atmega168pabb.build.mcu=atmega168p
atmega168pabb.build.f_cpu=8000000L
atmega168pabb.build.core=arduino:arduino
atmega168pabb.build.variant=arduino:standard
atmega168pabb.build.board=ATmega168PA_BreadBoard
```

Comment: Do you do an erase before the write?

Comment: @Ron Beyer I do not think I do. I have been using the Arduino IDE to upload the code, so I use the standard procedure one would do in order to reprogram the arduino. What would you suggest?

Comment: if you upload a sketch over ISP, you delete the bootloader

Comment: @RonBeyer How do I do the erase?

Comment: @Juraj Isn't the bootloader necessary in order to run the arduino code and use arduino IDE and libraries to standalone atmegas? How does it work if the bootloader is deleted?

Comment: the bootloader is only for upload over UART (a.k.a. Serial) and nothing else. the flashing over ISP erases all flash memory.

Comment: @Juraj If I do not reburn the bootloader, I cannot upload new code because it gives the "content missmatch" error. I understand what you are saying, perhaps you can help me with how to upload new code? Ron Beyer above suggested to do an erase before the write, but did not reply on how to do that.

Comment: turn on verbose mode for upload in IDE Preferences

Comment: @Juraj I went to File-> preferences and checked the "Show verbose output during Upload". The same verification error persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: and why do you try a serial upload if you didn't burn the bootloader? or why did you erase the bootloader with the upload of a sketch over ISP?

Comment: I do not understand what you suggest. As I have written, if I try to upload code to my standalone atmega, using arduino uno as ISP, I get the verification error. The only way so far to successfully upload code to the standalone atmega, is by burning the bootloader before trying the upload.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you haven't written the lock bit after loading the bootloader. If the lock bit isn't set to its "locked" state, the data will be overwritten by the code that you load and you will not be able to load a sketch a second time or any thereafter without erasing the memory and writing a new bootloader. You can make use of avrdude through the terminal, where you can specify the bootloader hex file you wish to load, and you can write the fuse bits and the lock bit as required for your microcontroller version.

You might find this blog entry useful: https://foraysinto3d.blogspot.com/2011/09/chapter-17-in-which-i-finally-burn.html

It also appears your boards.txt file has the same value written for lock_bits and unlock_bits:

```
atmega168pabb.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
atmega168pabb.bootloader.lock_bits=0x3F
```

**These entries should have different values** so that you can toggle the lock bit (it will not work if they are the same).

Here you can read about avrdude: https://avrdudes.github.io/avrdude/7.1/avrdude.html#Introduction

If you choose to make use of avrdude from the command line, the entries should look like this:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/avrdude -p atmega168p -c avrisp -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -e -v -C /home/myusername/Arduino/hardware/MiniCore/avr/avrdude.conf -Ulock:w:0xff:m -Uefuse:w:0xfc:m -Uhfuse:w:0xdf:m -Ulfuse:w:0xf7:m -Uflash:w:/home/myusername/Arduino/hardware/MiniCore/avr/bootloaders/optiboot_flash/bootloaders/atmega168p/16000000L/optiboot_flash_atmega168p_UART0_115200_16000000L_B5.hex:i
```

```
$ /usr/local/bin/avrdude -p atmega168p -c avrisp -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -v -D -Ulock:w:0xcf:m
```

In the first line, I write the lock bit OFF (unlocked):

```
-Ulock:w:0xff:m
```

and in the second line, once the bootloader is written and verified, I write the lock bit ON (locked):

```
-Ulock:w:0xcf:m
```

Of course, you should become familiar with the format for avrdude, and you should identify the specific command line options for your microcontroller.
In these lines you will see that I used Minicore, which offers support for your version of the ATmega168 (i.e. version PA). Make sure that the values you write for the fuses match those in the boards.txt file (in my case, the one from Minicore).

See Minicore: https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore

Also, please note that this method requires the use of an ICSP (I used an arduino pro mini loaded with the example ArduinoISP sketch that comes in the Arduino IDE, only having modified the baudrate based on my requirements, and it worked for me).